# How to overide extJS grid filter

Tags: javascript, extjs, overriding, extjs6

I am creating a new project in that I am using Grid.

Here is my grid.

```
Ext.define('myProj.view.base.grid.myGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myGrid',
    controller: 'myProj-controller-base-grid-myGridcontroller',
   requires: [
        "myProj.controller.base.grid.myGridcontroller",
        'Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',
        'Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer',
        'Ext.grid.filters.Filters',
    ],
    mixins: ['Deft.mixin.Injectable'],
    inject: ["gridStore"],
    config: {
        gridStore: null,
    },
    emptyText : "No data available",
    plugins: {
        gridfilters: true
    },
    overflowY: 'auto',
    width:'100%',
    stripeRows: false,
    columnLines: false,
    selModel: {
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',
        mode: 'SINGLE',
        allowDeselect: true
    },  
   initComponent: function () {
        let _this=this;
        Ext.apply(this, {
            store: this.getListGridStore(),
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Now I want to overideto my filter. I have writtent my override code I am looking many examples but I am not geeting how to connect these two codes. ANy help will be usefull.

The overide code which I wanted to place here look like this.

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.filters.filter.List, {
    createMenuItems: function (store) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the override works but the *createMenuItems* function is not called.

Did you define the filter for each column? Like in the code example shown [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.filter.List.html).

```
{
    dataIndex: 'rating',
    text: 'Rating',
    width: 75,
    filter: {
        type: 'list',
        value: 5
    }
}
```